# define colorebox with chapter

Tags: tcolorbox

I have defined the following:

```
{\theorembodyfont{\rmfamily}\newtheorem{Bsp}{Beispiel}[chapter]}
```

to use in the text

```
\begin{Bsp}
bla
bla
\end{Bsp}
```

Now I want to color just the "Beispiel" include chapter.
Please have a look at the images:
[image]

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) elliptical node to define a new style; in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261886/define-colorebox-with-chapter/261959?noredirect=1#comment628237_261959) it has been requested for the body to start on a new line:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit,backgrounds}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{ovalplain}%
  {\item[\rlap{%
    \vbox{%
      \hbox{%
        \hskip\labelsep%
          {\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
              (name)
              {{\theorem@headerfont##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}};
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}  
            \node[overlay,fill=yellow!50!orange,ellipse,fit=(name)] {};  
            \end{pgfonlayer}
            \node[inner sep=0pt] {\rule[-5ex]{0pt}{0pt}};  
            \end{tikzpicture}%
          }%    
      }%
      \hbox{\strut}%
    }%
    }]
  }%
  {\item[\rlap{%
    \vbox{%
      \hbox{%
        \hskip\labelsep%
          {\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
              (name)
              {{\theorem@headerfont##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator}};
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}  
            \node[overlay,fill=yellow!50!orange,ellipse,fit=(name)] {};  
            \end{pgfonlayer}
            \node[inner sep=0pt] {\rule[-5ex]{0pt}{0pt}};  
            \end{tikzpicture}%
          }%    
      }%
      \hbox{\strut}%
    }%
    }]
  }
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{ovalplain}
\theorembodyfont{\rmfamily}
\newtheorem{Bsp}{Beispiel}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}
\begin{Bsp}
A test example
\end{Bsp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome, is it possible to put the text "A test example" in a new line?

Comment: @user80497 Sure. Please see my updated answer.